# how to get upcoming time in from the list of time?

Tags: javascript, time, compare, momentjs

I am building a website using create-react-app and I need to get the upcoming time from the list as compared to the current time.
my time list is

```
  let times = [
    {
      time: "05:33",
    },
    {
      time: "12:20",
    },
    {
      time: "15:23",
    },
    {
      time: "17:46",
    },
    {
      time: "19:08",
    },
  ];
```

I have tried many solutions but all in vain, one solution that is also unsuccessful is

```
  const compareTime = moment().format("hh:mm");
  time7.map((item, i) => {
    console.log(
      Date.parse(
        `01/01/2011 ${format(parse(item.time, "HH:mm", new Date()), "hh:mm")}45`
      ) > Date.parse(`01/01/2011 ${compareTime}:10`)
    );
  });
```

I am super stuck in this and trying to solve this problem for almost a week I need a proper solution to get the upcoming time from the list any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest moving away from moment as it is now deprecated. Instead, try luxon - it's very similar but a lot lighter. I've kept my answer clear of any dependencies, though if you were using luxon or moment, you could simplify how I get the current time.

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentTime = new Date();
currentTime = currentTime.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')
+ currentTime.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
let futureTimes = times.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.time > currentTime;
})
.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.time < b.time ? -1 : a.time > b.time;
});

let nextTime = futureTimes.length ? future times[0] : null;
```

I probably need to double check it and tweak, but coding on my mobile is a little tough.

Simpler solution:

```
let currentTime = new Date();
currentTime = currentTime.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')
+ currentTime.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
let nextTime = times
.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.time < b.time ? -1 : a.time > b.time;
})
.find((obj) => {
    return obj.time > currentTime;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your time but is not working

Comment: Yer, there were a couple of typos courtesy of trying to code on mobile. JSFiddle seems to be terrible on mobile and isn't helping me debug JS. Need a proper console to debug it.